# Openstack API - Nova vs Ceilometer to Know Instance State

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, ceilometer

Does anyone knows a way to ask to openstack, through API, if a instance is running or not?
I don't even know if I have to ask to Ceilometer or Nova.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would ask Nova to get current state, and Ceilometer to get historical states (e.g. for billing). Assuming you've got a valid `nova` client:

```
 servers = nova.servers.list(detailed=True)
 for s in servers:
     print(s.status)
```

There are potentially other attributes that can give you more detailed information depending on your setup, e.g. extended status power state (you need to use `getattr` vs `.` because of the illegal identifier characters in the name):

```
 print(getattr(s, "os-extended-status:power_state"))
```